# Create a chat application in jquery-mobile/html5/css3 + phonegap?

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, cordova

I want to create a mobile chat application in jquery-mobile/html5/css3 + phonegap(client) and possibly java(server).

Is there probably a phonegap plugin?
Do you know a good tutorial?
How would you realise such an application?

I have never done sth. like that before so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: A similar question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609559/creating-a-mobile-chat-app-with-phonegap-best-strategy

Comment: why -1? its a valid question if you haven`t done that before...

Comment: @user1248720 you probably got the downvotes because discussions are discouraged here on stackoverflow. You actually ask 3 questions, which cannot be really answered. Remember that Stackoverflow is not a forum, but a Q&A site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not possible without some kind of server backend, cause you'll need a database to store the messages to share between the relevent users.

Comment: so when i possibly would use google app engine as backend, what technologie would you use to send/get the messages?

Comment: yeah I guess you could do it that way, but you realise you've just shifted the responsibility for the backend to google, you've not changed the problem.  If you want to communicate using javascript, better using JSON, cause it'll work with almost everything.  you can perhaps use JSON.js to convert your javascript array to json, or use jquery's internal functions.